# How to work with a model with two input in LIME for explaining text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text-classification, lime

My Keras model is the Following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gfun.png 
It takes two phrases and the result is the relation between them, that can be either "Attack, Support, Neither".

Now, i want to explain the output of this model with LIME, i tried the following:

```
from lime.lime_text import LimeTextExplainer
explainer = LimeTextExplainer(class_names = ['Attack','Defence','Neither'])

def new_predict(testo):
  print(testo)
  testo_split = testo.split("/")
  print(testo_split)
  testo1 = testo_split[0]
  print(testo1)
  testo2 = testo_split[1]
  print(testo2)
  print("DATAFRAME")
  row_cani = {'testo1' : [testo1] , 'testo2' : [testo2]}
  df_cani = pd.DataFrame(row_cani)
  print(df_cani)
  df_cani['testo_token1'] = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_cani['testo1'])
  df_cani['testo_token2']  = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_cani['testo2'])
  df_cani['testo_token_padding1'] = pad_sequences(df_cani['testo_token1'], padding = "post", maxlen = max_len).tolist()
  df_cani['testo_token_padding2'] = pad_sequences(df_cani['testo_token2'], padding = "post", maxlen = max_len).tolist()
  valori_df_testo1_cani = df_cani['testo_token_padding1'].values 
  valori_df_testo2_cani = df_cani['testo_token_padding2'].values 
  valori_testo1_cani = np.array([item for item in valori_df_testo1_cani])
  valori_testo2_cani = np.array([item for item in valori_df_testo2_cani])
  return model_final.predict([valori_testo1_cani, valori_testo2_cani])

frase_cani_argomento = "You hear barking and howling in the distance."
frase_cani_claim = "there are dogs nearby."
testo = frase_cani_argomento + " /" + frase_cani_claim
exp = explainer.explain_instance(testo, new_predict)
exp.show_in_notebook(text = True)
```

Now, when i pass the string `testo` in `explainer.explain_instance(testo, new_predict)` inside the function this string becomes this:

```
['You hear barking and howling in the distance. /there are dogs nearby.', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/', '/', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/', '/', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', 'You hear barking and howling in the distance. /', '/there are dogs nearby.', '/', '/there are dogs nearby.', ...]
```

Do you have any idea why this happens? i tried to explain a model with a single text input and it worked, but with multiple inputs my program have sone problem.